# Declaring forEach globally and using it in functions

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

I have a JSON named employees of 10 elements in it, like below

```
{
   "name" : "Prem",
   "dob"  : "10-10-1992"
},
```

With three buttons, each has a specific function

```
document.getElementById('btn-25').addEventListener('click',ageCategory25)
document.getElementById('btn-50').addEventListener('click',ageCategory50)
document.getElementById('btn-100').addEventListener('click',ageCategory100)

const output = document.getElementById('result2')


function ageCategory25(){
    output.innerHTML =''
     employees.forEach(function(employee){
        const ageFilter = getAge(employee.dob)
        if(ageFilter < 25 ){
            output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
        }
    })
}

function ageCategory50(){
    output.innerHTML =''
    employees.forEach(function(employee){
        const ageFilter = getAge(employee.dob)
         if(ageFilter >= 25 && ageFilter<=50){
            output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
       }
    })
}

function ageCategory100(){
    output.innerHTML =''
    employees.forEach(function(employee){
        const ageFilter = getAge(employee.dob)
         if(ageFilter >= 50 && ageFilter<=100){
            output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
       }
    })
}


function getAge(date){
    const currentAge = Math.floor((new Date() - new Date(date).getTime())/31556925994)
    return currentAge
}
```

The above code works correctly, i'm able to get the result as per the age mentioned in the buttons.
But, I'm declaring forEach loop in all functions, is there a way to declare forEach once globally and use it in all functions. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, you could have one function called from all your buttons, if you just tell it the thing it needs to do differently each time. In this case it seems the parameters of the if statement appear to be the only thing which varies, so those values would be the things to use as the input parameters for your single function. (P.S. the ability to abstract your code like this and pick out the things which are variable and the things which are the same each time is a key skill if you want to be able to write lean, non-repetitive code).

Comment: @ADyson Thank you so much for your valuable note :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive 25,50,100 in a function.

```
document.getElementById('btn-25').addEventListener('click',()=>ageCategory(25))
document.getElementById('btn-50').addEventListener('click',()=>ageCategory(50))
document.getElementById('btn-100').addEventListener('click',()=>ageCategory(100))


function ageCategory(n){
    output.innerHTML =''
    employees.forEach(function(employee){
        const ageFilter = getAge(employee.dob)
        if(n === 25 && ageFilter < 25 ){
            output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
        }
        else if(n === 50 && ageFilter >= 25 && ageFilter<=50){
            output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
        }
        else if(n === 100 && ageFilter >= 50 && ageFilter<=100){
            output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
        }
    })
}
```

**UPDATED:**
I think it can be a little better:

```
function ageCategory(n) {
    output.innerHTML = '';
    let filter;
    if      (n === 25)   { filter = (x) => (x < 25);            }
    else if (n === 50)   { filter = (x) => (x >= 25 && x <= 50) }
    else if (n === 100)  { filter = (x) => (x >= 50 && x<=100)  }
    employees.forEach(function(employee){
        const ageFilter = getAge(employee.dob);
        if(filter(ageFilter)){
            output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the one I was expecting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create the function like:

```
function ageCategory(age){
  output.innerHTML =''
  employees.forEach(function(employee){
    const ageFilter = getAge(employee.dob)
    if(age == 25 && ageFilter < 25 ){
      output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
    }
    else if(age == 50 && ageFilter >= 25 && ageFilter <= 50){
      output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
    } 
    else if(age == 100 && ageFilter >= 50 && ageFilter <= 100){
      output.innerHTML += `<h3> ${employee.name} </h3>`
    }
  }    
}
```

Then use the function as call back of `addEventListener()` by passing the age like the following way:

```
document.getElementById('btn-25').addEventListener('click', ageCategory(25));
document.getElementById('btn-50').addEventListener('click', ageCategory(50));
document.getElementById('btn-100').addEventListener('click', ageCategory(100));
```